# Where and how to save Android GCM project ID and api key?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on Android gcm project. The docs recommend to save the project ID and api key in a server for security purposes. But all of the GCM examples in the web don't do that. How efficient would that be to save them in a server and grab them when needed in the app? Has anyone done that in any project? Can someone give me a snippet of efficient code?
Thank you

Comment: the server its saved to is your own server. There is no "server" that is awaiting for you to save it to. That key is used so your server can send pushes to that specific device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCM implementations require you to have server side part that will be sending data to your devices. This acts as middleware between devices and GCM servers. Server side can be PHP/Python etc scripts, whatever. And to these scripts need these data to be able to send anything to your devices via Google servers. So your app is NOT fetching anything. Like this:

[image].

Comment: I get that. My question is for the device to register for the first time it is required to provide the sender id(which is project id) and api key to be authenticated and receive registration id. The docs state not to save these parameters in the app in case the user decompiles the app and gets them. So it is recommended to save them in our server. How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: If user decompile your app he will only get your gcmProjectId. But this will not let him send anything to your users. Or I do not see what you are worrying about?

Comment: No that was it. I was following Google's tutorial and wanted to follow the recommended procedures. Thank you for your time.